# GhostScript: rendering PDF fonts as glyphs - aborts because 'Could not find default_gray.icc'

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

This script used to work for me, rendering fonts in a PDF as glyph paths so they don't come out crippled when editing the file in Inkscape:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "x$1" = "x" -o "x$2" = "x" ]; then
    echo Usage: `basename "$0"` "<input.pdf>" "<output.pdf>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=- -q -dbatch \
   -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET "$1" -c quit | ps2pdf - "$2"
```

However now, on a new computer (Debian Stretch), it produces errors when running:

```
$ pdf-fonts-to-outlines in.pdf out.pdf
  ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1148: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc 
| ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1789: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile
Error: /undefined in Unknown
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1999   1   3   %oparray_pop   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1982   1   3   %oparray_pop   1868   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1209/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.20: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

How do I fix this? (in this case, the input PDF has colours. I don't want to convert any colour spaces etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually answered in a question over at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546677/embedfonts-complains-about-unknown-device-pswrite#24546678):

> the device is called `ps2write` these days.

Changing `pswrite` for `ps2write` fixes the issue.